# How to do many-to-many relationship without deleting the previous data in mapping table using Hibernate or JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I have 2 Entities : **User.java** and **PushNotification.java**
and mapping table named as **userpushnotification** where many-to-many mapping takes place. 
the existing data in userpushnotification table is a kind of important for me. 
So if i try to add **users**(let's say id=5,6,7) for **pushnotification**(id=2), hibernate deletes the previous data for pushnotification(id=2) in relationship table and then it adds the new users for that pushnotification(id=2).
My need is to keep all the records in relationship table.
So how can i restrict the Hibernate/JPA to execute only insert queries intstead of executing delete and insert queries.
In simple words, I just want to append data in relationship table instead of overwriting.

User.java :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "identity")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "gen")
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "authkey")
    private String authKey;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<PushNotifications> pushNotifications = new HashSet<PushNotifications>();
```

PushNotifications.java :-

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pushnotifications", uniqueConstraints =     @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "id" }))

public class PushNotifications implements Serializable {
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GenericGenerator(name="gen",strategy="identity")
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
private long id;

@Column(name = "shortdescription")
private String shortDescription;

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "userpushnotifications", 
joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "pushnotificatoinId") }, 
inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "userId") })
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
```

When i try to do this :

```
   PushNotifications notifications = iNotificationService
                    .getNotification(notificationId);
                    Set<User> newUsers = new HashSet<User>();
          newUsers .add(newUserToBeNotified_1);
          newUsers .add(newUserToBeNotified_2);

    notifications.setUsers(newUsers);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(notifications);
```

Here, am tring to add 2 users for that notification type, Already there is one user for that notification type in relationship table.
Hibernate executing these queries :

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        userpushnotifications 
    where
        pushnotificatoinId=? 
        and userId=?
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        userpushnotifications
        (pushnotificatoinId, userId) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        userpushnotifications
        (pushnotificatoinId, userId) 
    values
        (?, ?)
```

So, i hope u got me, i dont want hibernate to make delete operations.
Please help me resolve this, Looking for answers...
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is this line notifications.setUsers(newUsers); Why are you creating a new set?

Comment: its because , i have used 
Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(); while declaring many-to-may mapping in PushNotifications  entity, so i have to pass Set of User as parameter for mapping process right?

Comment: when tried getting the existing users by calling notifications.getUsers(); and adding the newusers to this set is not scalable because if i want to add only one user, i had to get the 5000 existing user for no reason and it takes pretty much time. Thanks

Comment: But that way you delete it because you create a new set. And mapping a collection that contains more than around 100 is not a good idea. You will never need that

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#core-quick-start) for this which works on top of JPA and provides support for DML operations for collections. A query could look like the following

```
criteriaBuilderFactory.insertCollection(entityManager, PushNotifications.class, "users")
    .fromIdentifiableValues(User.class, "u", newUsers)
    .bind("id", notification.getId())
    .bind("users").select("u")
    .executeUpdate();
```

After setting Blaze-Persistence up like described in the [documentation](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#environments-spring) you can create a repository like this:

```
@Component
class MyRepository {
  @Autowired CriteriaBuilderFactory cbf;
  @Autowired EntityManager em;

  public void addUsers(Collection<User> newUsers) {
    cbf.insertCollection(em, PushNotifications.class, "users")
    .fromIdentifiableValues(User.class, "u", newUsers)
    .bind("id", notification.getId())
    .bind("users").select("u")
    .executeUpdate();
  }
}
```

This will issue just the insert into the join table.